How to check if an entry is the first occurence of a string in a dataframe
I have a dataframe like the example:
  client year
1      a 2021
2      b 2021
3      a 2022
4      c 2022
5      a 2023
6      b 2023
7      c 2023
8      d 2023

and would like to add a column to check wether the client has already shown up before, like this:
  client year previous
1      a 2021    FALSE
2      b 2021    FALSE
3      a 2022     TRUE
4      c 2022    FALSE
5      a 2023     TRUE
6      b 2023     TRUE
7      c 2023     TRUE
8      d 2023    FALSE

so far, i've tried this: df %>% mutate(previous = client %in% pull(df[df$year<year,], client)), but it takes a very long time to run and returns only FALSE values.
the other solution I can think of is to make a separate data frame with distinct values and then compare year>distinct$year, is there a more efficient way to do this?

You can do this duplicated i.e df$previous <- duplicated(df$client)
